# Can not load file or assembly error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-assembly

When I run a project in Visual Studio Community 2015 it gives me this
error:

> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
>   Can not load file or assembly
>   or one of its dependencies WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 The file can not be
>   found.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `Modernizr` NuGet package using the command into NuGet package manager console.

```
Install-Package Modernizr
```

and `WebGrease` using

```
Install-Package WebGrease
```

Here are the packages [Modernizr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Modernizr/)
[WebGrease](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebGrease/)

Comment: That did not work, this is what i get: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Web.Optimization.dll

Comment: try updated answer you need to install another package

Comment: thats great, happy coding :)